How to order and limit for a unique column value SQL
if I run the following query in sql (bigquery googleSQL) it will give me a list of sales per country for the current date
SELECT
    date,
    product,
    country,
    sum(total_sales) as total_sales
    FROM
    `international_sales`
    WHERE 
    date = '2024-10-19'
    AND
    total_sales > 0
    AND product in ( 'Product A', 'Product B')




date
product
country
total_sales




2024-10-19
Product A
United States
22222


2024-10-19
Product B
Canada
111111


2024-10-19
Product B
Mexico
333333



I want to be able to modify this so I only get the top ten highest countries for each product. if I was only querying one product it would be as simple as adding
order by total_sales desc limit 10;

but is made more difficult by the fact that I'm trying to query multiple products at once. How can I get around this?

include a row number calculation such as row_number() over(partition by date, product, country order by total_sales) as rn  then filter for where rn <= 10

Hi @Murphstar, I have posted a community answer as per the comments for the sake of community who might encounter this issue in future, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. Please feel free to edit the answer for any additional information.

As commented by @Paul Maxwell, for your requirement, you can include a row number calculation such as given below,
row_number() over(partition by date, product, country order by total_sales) as rn then filter for where rn <= 10 .
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
